# Building Python in Sublime Text

Tags: python, build, sublimetext2, build-error

I am unable to get a Python system to build on a friend's computer which runs Windows XP SP3 using Sublime Text 2. We reinstalled Python 2.7.3 and also Sublime Text 2 and still are having trouble with this. Our `Python.sublime-build` field says:

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\Python27\\python.exe", "-u", "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

When we try to build simple Python programs, such as:

```
2 * 2
```

Sublime Text will not build the system, and will instead spit out:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in ''
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

It would be wonderful if I could get some help with this. Thank you so much whoever assists me with this!

Comment: add `if __name__ == '__main__':
print 2*2`

Comment: So do you have a `__main__` module?

Answer (score 12):

I fixed this by saving my file as a .py file. I opened up a new file, added some code, and tried to build it, which gave me that error. After saving as a .py file, I was able to build and run fine.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't save the file. You need to save the file like name_fila.py then you'll be able to run it

Answer (score 0):

I used this for Python 3.4 and it works pretty good

The current path you put seems to be the issue.

`"$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"` --> `"$file"`

`{
    "cmd": ["C:\\Python34\\python.exe", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}`

Alexandre

Answer (score -1):

i think you should make a `__main__` like this `__name__ == '__main__'` module then try to compile it ...